# Lambda in a loop

Tags: python, loops, anonymous-function

Considering the following code snippet:

```
# directorys == {'login': <object at ...>, 'home': <object at ...>}
for d in directorys:
    self.command["cd " + d] = (lambda : self.root.change_directory(d))
```

I expect to create a dictionary of two function as following :

```
# Expected :
self.command == {
    "cd login": lambda: self.root.change_directory("login"),
    "cd home": lambda: self.root.change_directory("home")
}
```

but it looks like the two lambda function generated are exactly the same :

```
# Result :
self.command == {
    "cd login": lambda: self.root.change_directory("login"),
    "cd home": lambda: self.root.change_directory("login")   # <- Why login ?
}
```

I really don't understand why. Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You need to bind d for each function created. One way to do that is to pass it as a parameter with a default value:

```
lambda d=d: self.root.change_directory(d)
```

Now the d inside the function uses the parameter, even though it has the same name, and the default value for that is evaluated when the function is created. To help you see this:

```
lambda bound_d=d: self.root.change_directory(bound_d)
```

Remember how default values work, such as for mutable objects like lists and dicts, because you are binding an object.

This idiom of parameters with default values is common enough, but may fail if you introspect function parameters and determine what to do based on their presence.  You can avoid the parameter with another closure:

```
(lambda d=d: lambda: self.root.change_directory(d))()
# or
(lambda d: lambda: self.root.change_directory(d))(d)
```

Comment: I did not realize default values were allowed in lambdas. Passing a lambda with a default argument as a keyword argument just looks weird: `command = lambda path = path: selected(path)`.

Comment: Yes thats correct, but what can I do, if the signature of function is declared, imagine the case of a bind or trace function of tkinter.

Answer (score 34):

This is due to the point at which d is being bound. The lambda functions all point at the *variable* `d` rather than the current *value* of it, so when you update `d` in the next iteration, this update is seen across all your functions.

For a simpler example:

```
funcs = []
for x in [1,2,3]:
  funcs.append(lambda: x)

for f in funcs:
  print f()

# output:
3
3
3
```

You can get around this by adding an additional function, like so:

```
def makeFunc(x):
  return lambda: x

funcs = []
for x in [1,2,3]:
  funcs.append(makeFunc(x))

for f in funcs:
  print f()

# output:
1
2
3
```

You can also fix the scoping inside the lambda expression

```
lambda bound_x=x: bound_x
```

However in general this is **not** good practice as you have changed the signature of your function.

Comment: Is this same problem that occurs with defining closures within for-loops using ```def```, that in Python for-loops don't get their own scopes?

Comment: @robbie_c An interesting behavior to support your first example: if you `del x` after the loop where you create and append the various functions, calling `f()` will throw a NameError complaining that `x` does not exist.

Answer (score 18):

Alternatively, instead of `lambda`, you can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) which, in my opinion, has a cleaner syntax.

Instead of:

```
for d in directorys:
    self.command["cd " + d] = (lambda d=d: self.root.change_directory(d))
```

it will be:

```
for d in directorys:
    self.command["cd " + d] = partial(self.root.change_directory, d)
```

---

Or, here is another simple example:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

lambdas = [lambda: print(number) 
           for number in numbers]
lambdas_with_binding = [lambda number=number: print(number) 
                        for number in numbers]
partials = [partial(print, number) 
            for number in numbers]

for function in lambdas:
    function()
# 3 3 3
for function in lambdas_with_binding:
    function()
# 1 2 3
for function in partials:
    function()
# 1 2 3
```

Comment: This is a clearly better approach and I make sure to recommend it when the opportunity arises. The `lambda x=x` trick is not just unintuitive, it exploits the same behaviour that is [a classic gotcha in another context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument). Binding arguments using `functools.partial` is explicit, and also [eta-reduced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B7-reduction) (which makes it more DRY). Oh, also that default parameter could be overridden, but shouldn't be - a potential pitfall.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem. The selected solution helped me a lot, but I consider necessary to add a precision to make functional the code of the question: define the lambda function outside of the loop. By the way, default value is not necessary.

```
foo = lambda d: lambda : self.root.change_directory(d)
for d in directorys:
    self.command["cd " + d] = (foo(d))
```

Comment: Cleanest and best answer in my opinion. It reminds me of all that stuff in lambda calculus, lambda x. lambda y. ...

Comment: @JonathanMugan How is it cleaner than `self.command["cd " + d] = lambda d=d: self.root.change_directory(d)`?