# Is it possible to know the button name through function

Tags: python-2.7, button, tkinter

I am using 20 buttons and the when click any one of the button i am calling a "btn_click" function.Is it possible to know the Button name(which button pressed)through that function.Please Find the code snippet below.

```
    t=['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','untill to twenty']
    for i in range(1,20):
         obj=Button(root1,text=t[i],command=btn_click,width=27)
         obj.grid(row=i,column=0,sticky=W,padx=15,pady=15)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the name of the button as a parameter to the callback function.

```
def btn_click(button_name):
    print button_name
```

Then you can create a `lambda`, passing the current name to the callback.

```
t = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'untill to twenty']
for i, x in enumerate(t):
     obj = Button(root1, text=x, command=lambda name=x: btn_click(name), width=27)
     obj.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky=W, padx=15, pady=15)
```

Note, however, that [`lambda` can behave unexpectedly when used inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19837486/1639625), thus the `name=x` default paramter. Or use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) instead:

```
     obj = Button(root1, text=x, command=functools.partial(btn_click, x), width=27)
```