# Python Generator "chain" in a for loop

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to set up a "processing pipeline" for data that I'm reading in from a data source, and applying a sequence of operators (using generators) to each item as it is read.

Some sample code that demonstrates the same issue.

```
def reader():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3

def add_1(val):
    return val + 1

def add_5(val):
    return val + 5

def add_10(val):
    return val + 10

operators = [add_1, add_5, add_10]

def main():
    vals = reader()

    for op in operators:
        vals = (op(val) for val in vals)

    return vals

print(list(main()))
```

**Desired** : `[17, 18, 19]`
**Actual**: `[31, 32, 33]`

Python seems to not be saving the value of `op` each time through the for loop, so it instead applies the third function each time. **Is there a way to "bind" the actual operator function to the generator expression each time through the for loop?**

I could get around this trivially by changing the generator expression in the for loop to a list comprehension, but since the actual data is much larger, I don't want to be storing it all in memory at any one point.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! The `map` solution worked best for me, since there are other things I want to do in the for loop as well (related to logging, additional checks, etc.). In my real program, each `operator` is actually a class with `__call__`, and has some other functions and attributes I need to deal with.  

The `reduce` solution would also work well, but loses the ability to do that without wrapping each operator in a function to perform those extra actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force a variable to be bound by creating the generator in a new function. eg.

```
def map_operator(operator, iterable):
    # closure value of operator is now separate for each generator created
    return (operator(item) for item in iterable)

def main():
    vals = reader()
    for op in operators:
        vals = map_operator(op, vals)   
    return vals
```

However, `map_operator` is pretty much identical to the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) builtin (in python 3.x). So just use that instead.

Comment: In Python 2, make sure to use [`itertools.imap`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap). I learned this the hard way.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a little helper which composes the functions *but in reverse order*:

```
import functools

def compose(*fns):
    return functools.reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: g(f(x)), fns)
```

I.e. you can use `compose(f,g,h)` to generate a lambda expression equivalent to `lambda x: h(g(f(x)))`. This order is uncommon, but ensures that your functions are applied left-to-right (which is probably what you expect):

Using this, your `main` becomes just

```
def main():
    vals = reader()
    f = compose(add_1, add_5, add_10)
    return (f(v) for v in vals)
```

Comment: Good point on the order, I didn't think about that. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Note that this changes the order of operations: I.e., OP's code first calculates `op_1` for all the values, then `op_5`, etc., while yours first applies all the operations to `val_1`, then to `val_2`, etc. Depending on the application, this might be perfectly okay or a problem. (Just wanted to point out)

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you want - create a composite function:

```
import functools

def compose(functions):
    return functools.reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: g(f(x)), functions, lambda x: x)

def reader():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3

def add_1(val):
    return val + 1

def add_5(val):
    return val + 5

def add_10(val):
    return val + 10

operators = [add_1, add_5, add_10]

def main():
    vals = map(compose(operators), reader())
    return vals

print(list(main()))
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this problem is that you are creating a deeply nested generator of generators and evaluate the whole thing *after* the loop, when `op` has been bound to the last element in the list -- similar to the quite common ["lambda in a loop"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19837486/1639625) problem.

In a sense, your code is roughly equivalent to this:

```
for op in operators:
    pass

print(list((op(val) for val in (op(val) for val in (op(val) for val in (x for x in [1, 2, 3])))))
```

One (not very pretty) way to fix this would be to `zip` the values with *another* generator, repeating the same operation:

```
def add(n):
    def add_n(val):
        return val + n
    return add_n
operators = [add(n) for n in [1, 5, 10]]

import itertools
def main():
    vals = (x for x in [1, 2, 3])

    for op in operators:
        vals = (op(val) for (val, op) in zip(vals, itertools.repeat(op)))

    return vals

print(list(main()))
```