# Python Tkinter changing label text

Tags: python, tkinter

I know that there are a lot of questions dealing with tkinter but I have looked at a bunch of them and none of them seem to help me.

```
import tkinter

class Calculator:

  def __init__(self):
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.geometry("200x300")
    window.title("Calculator")

    lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="placeholder", bg="blue", textvariable="labelText")
    lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

    self.firstNumArray = []
    self.secondNumArray = []
    self.operation = ""
    self.currentNum = "first"

    def appendNumber(self, number):
      print("Appending Number")
      if self.currentNum == "first":
        self.firstNumArray.append(number)
        print("".join(str(x) for x in self.firstNumArray))
        lbl.config(text="".join(str(x) for x in self.firstNumArray))
        window.update()
      else:
        self.secondNumArray.append(number)

    for i in range(1,4):
      string = "Creating button at ({0},{1})".format(0,i)
      print(string)
      button = tkinter.Button(text=i, command=lambda: appendNumber(self, i))
      button.grid(row=1, column=i-1)

    for i in range(1,4):
      string = "Creating button at ({0},{1})".format(1,i)
      print(string)
      button = tkinter.Button(text=i+3, command=lambda: appendNumber(self, i+3))
      button.grid(row=2, column=i-1)

    for i in range(1,4):
      string = "Creating button at ({0},{1})".format(2,i)
      print(string)
      button = tkinter.Button(text=i+6, command=lambda: appendNumber(self, i+6))
      button.grid(row=3, column=i-1)


    div = tkinter.Button(text="/")
    mult = tkinter.Button(text="*")
    add = tkinter.Button(text="+")
    sub = tkinter.Button(text="-")

    add.grid(row=1, column=3)
    sub.grid(row=2, column=3)
    mult.grid(row=3, column=3)
    div.grid(row=4, column=3)

    button = tkinter.Button(text="0")
    button.grid(row=4, column=1)

    window.mainloop()



calc = Calculator()
```

When I launch the program the window opens. When I click on a button the text in the label does not change. I have tried using a `StringVar` as the `textvariable` and then calling the `set()` function, but that did not work either. I think it has to do with the scope of the function. I had to place the `appendNumber()` function inside the `__init__()` because for some reason `self.lbl = tkinter.Label()` makes nothing pop up at all.

Comment: I can see that you have an unused `textvariable` with a label.try to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

1. `labelText` should, of course, be a `StringVar` and not a string...

   ```
   labelText = tkinter.StringVar()
   lbl = tkinter.Label(window, bg="blue", textvariable=labelText)
   lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
   ```
2. Now you can use `labelText.set` to update the text. Also, no need for `self` parameter or `window.update`

   ```
   def appendNumber(number):
       if self.currentNum == "first":
           self.firstNumArray.append(number)
           labelText.set("".join(str(x) for x in self.firstNumArray))
       else:
           self.secondNumArray.append(number)
   ```
3. You can put all the buttons in one loop using `//` (*integer (!)* division) and `%` (modulo) operations. Also, be aware that the variable in the `lambda` is evaluated when the function is called, not when it is declared, i.e. all the `lambdas` will use the last value of `i` (`9` in this case) -- see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19837486/1639625). As a remedy, use `lambda n=i+1: appendNumber(n)`.

   ```
   for i in range(9):
       btn = tkinter.Button(text=i+1, command=lambda n=i+1: appendNumber(n))
       btn.grid(row=i//3+1, column=i%3)
   ```
4. Not really a problem, but since you don't need a reference to those buttons, you can make your code a bit more compact (same for the others):

   ```
   tkinter.Button(text="/").grid(row=1, column=3)
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!