# Tracking down text form kivy dropdown button

Tags: python, kivy

Hi Guys I have a question about kivy `DropDown`. I have this example:

```
def dropdownbutton(self):
    dropdown = DropDown()
    classlist = ['Barbarian', 'Knight', 'Sorcerer', 'Typical Seba', 'Hunter']
    for index in classlist:
        btn = Button(text='%s' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)
        btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))
        dropdown.add_widget(btn)
    mainbutton = Button(text='Class', size_hint=(None, None))
    mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)
    dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text',
                                                        x))  
    return mainbutton
```

And what I want to do, is to track current `btn.txt` which I choose, mby its dumb, but I spend about hour on this... Can you help me? 
`btn.text` returns me `Hunter` all the time

Comment: I don't have a clue what your issue is. The default button has text `Class`, returns the splitted `classlist` as buttons in `DropDown` and on click at the dropdown button the text changes properly. Any more explanation, screenshot or more code, please?

Comment: Yes, you are right, text changes properly on `DropDown` button,  but I need to store text from button in different variable, to initiate class **base** on chosen button :) For Example if I choose button `Knight` i want to create instance of  `class Knight` with `btn.text`, and i know how to do it, but I can't retrieve current `btn.text`

Answer (score 0):

You've hit this [classic problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837486/python-lambda-in-a-loop) with defining lambda functions in a loop. Try:

```
btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn=btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))
```

Comment: I don't think so, I think that the problem is in this line: `dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text',  x))`  In here we set text to the `mainbutton` but also I want to put chosen `btn.text` to variable and use it other way.

Answer (score 0):

So I made kind of work around with this class:

```
class DropdownList(Button):

    def __init__(self, label, labels):
        Button.__init__(self,
                        text=label,
                        size_hint=(None, None))

        self.buttons = []
        self.list = DropDown()

        for label in labels:
            b = Button(text=label, notify=None, callback=None)
            b.size_hint = (None, None)
            self.buttons.append(b)
            self.list.add_widget(b)

        self.bind(on_release=self.list.open)`
```

With this class I can attach special behavior to every button like this:

```
def build(self):
        classlist = ['Barbarian', 'Knight', 'Sorcerer', 'Typical Seba', 'Hunter']
        self.lst = DropdownList("Class", classlist)
        self.lst.buttons[0].bind(on_release=self.randomfunction)
        print self.lst.buttons[0].text
```

In behavior method I have to pass `event` as a argument:

```
def randomfunction(self, event):
        print "random string"
```

But there is still few problems here. I can't `setattr` to change text of the `self.list DropDown` button. Am'I missing something here? I just want to have two behavior's on every button. One: to take text from chosen button and put it to DropDown button, and close it. Second: with text from chosen button create instance of class with the same name as button... I will leave it like it is for now, but if anyone can solve it it will be great