# Is there any way to get information on the tkinter menu button just clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `for:`loop which creates a tkinter menu cascade for every mailbox my email server has, all pointing to the same command, here's that code:

```
menubar = Menu (rootA)
    foldermenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    for i in range(len(mailboxes)):
        foldermenu.add_command(label=mailboxes[i], command=switchBox)
```

But I need a way to identify exactly which button was clicked within my code, so is there any way to return the 'label' of the menu selection you just made or return an index or otherwise? for example the tkinter listbox has the function `.curselection()`

Comment: Unrelated, but you can just use `command=switchBox`, without `lambda` and `()`

Comment: Oh yeah thanks! I was passing some variables through previously whilst trying to get this to work and must have forgotten to remove it.

Comment: Or you could pass the `i` to the lambda; in this case, remember that the variables in the lambda are evaluated when the function is called, not when it is defined (see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19837486/1639625)), i.e. use something like `command=lambda x=i: switchBox(x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the mail box to the callback. This is the main reason why you would want to use `lambda`. If you don't pass any values, there's no point in using `lambda`.

```
def switchBox(mailbox):
    ...

foldermenu.add_command(..., command=lambda mbox=mailboxes[i]: switchBox(mbox))
...
```

Note: this works because we are binding the value of `mbox` at the time the `lambda` is created. For more information about `lambda` and binding values, see [What do (lambda) function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture)

Comment: This is perfect! I'd been trying to do something similar but was always getting the last mailbox in the loop because of my formatting, thank you!