# Converting a method with 2 variables to one variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function `foo` that takes 2 arguments `a` and `b`. I want to create a list of functions that are similar to `foo`, but value of `a` is fixed.

```
def foo(a,b): 
   return a*b

fooList = []
for i in range(n):
   fooList.append(foo(i))
```

I want `fooList[i]` to return a function that is similar to `foo(i, b)`.

Comment: Use `lambda` or `functools.partial`. But beware late binding: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19837486/3001761

Comment: This is a simple example. I might use a more complex function instead of simple foo.

Comment: Well, so what? You still use the same tools to do it.

Comment: Partial should work in my case. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial

def foo(a, b):
    return a * b

fooList = []
for i in range(n):
   fooList.append(partial(foo, i))
```

Then you'd do `fooList[i](5)` to calculate `i * 5`.

---

You can also curry `lambda` functions, somewhat like this:

```
for i in range(n):
    fooList.append((lambda x: lambda y: x * y)(i))
```

You can then call that the same way as above.

Comment: @idjaw https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying :)

Comment: ...you test this? Binding `lambda`s in a loop has behaviour that may surprise you.

Comment: If you are naming your lambda, you shouldn't be using a lambda!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Erm, good point. Fixed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I had no idea about late binding. Thanks, I learned something new.

Comment: Tested this code and it works as expected for the curried lambda functions.