# Dictionary With Lambda Values Updates All Entries

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, namedtuple

I'm in Python 2.7. I have two classes and one namedtuple. One class houses a dictionary as an instance attribute and a function that assigns to that dictionary. (This is a very simplified version of the situation). The namedtuple is simple enough. The other class is one that adds entries into `test_dict` via the `add_to_test_dict` function call.

Then I instantiate DictManipulator and call the `test` function:

```
from collections import namedtuple


class DictHolder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_dict = {}
    def add_to_test_dict(self, key, val):
        self.test_dict[key] = val

TestTuple = namedtuple('TestTuple', 'name data')

class DictManipulator(object):
    def test(self):
        named_tuple_list = [TestTuple(name='key1', data=1), TestTuple(name='key2', data=1000)]
        self.my_dh = DictHolder()
        for item in named_tuple_list:
            self.my_dh.add_to_test_dict(item.name, lambda: item.data)

my_dm = DictManipulator()
my_dm.test()
print('key1 value: ', my_dm.my_dh.test_dict['key1']())
print('key2 value: ', my_dm.my_dh.test_dict['key2']())
# ('key1 value: ', 1000)
# ('key2 value: ', 1000)
```

Why do both keys return the same value there? I have experimented enough to say that the original named_tuple_list is not updated, and I've tried to use `lambda: copy.deepcopy(item.data)`, but that doesn't work either. Thanks very much, folks.

Comment: Typical late binding issue. Try `lambda x=item: x.data` in your loop instead.

Comment: You beautiful person! Thanks for the assistance. It's working as I expect now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a typical late binding issue (see [common gotchas](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures)): when the functions (being lambda/anonymous has nothing to do with it) are called, they access the current value of `item`, which is the last one from the loop. Try

```
lambda x=item: x.data
```

in your loop instead. This works since default arguments are bound to a function at definition time while common local variables are evaluated at calling time.

Similar (possible duplicate) question: [Python Lambda in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837486/python-lambda-in-a-loop)

Comment: I appreciate the clarification. This was a blindspot for me.

Comment: @semi.suite Yeah, this is a common gotcha in Python :) I linked the hitchhikers section on the topic.