# Scheduled tasks in ensure_future are overlapping by the last one

Tags: asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I need a new handler that use another existing handler for processing multiple requests at once:

```
async def process_multiple_queries(request):
    init_request = request.clone()
    body = await request.json()

    for query in body["queries"]:

        @asyncio.coroutine
        def fake_json(self):
            return query

        # Replace request body on new fake json
        R = init_request.clone()
        R.json = fake_json.__get__(R, Request)

        # Process request in the background task
        asyncio.ensure_future(process_query(R))

async def process_query(request):
    body = await request.json()
    # ... Process body ...
    return web.json_response({"result": "OK"})
```

However, results of all scheduled tasks are equal to the result of the last task, i.e. bodies of all requests passed in `process_query` are equal only to the body of the last request.

But if I add `asyncio.sleep(5)` after `asyncio.ensure_future(process_query(R))`, all tasks are processed properly and produce different results.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the [well-known](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19837486/1600898) Python gotcha where a closure captures variables by name and not by value. As a result, all instances of the `fake_json` coroutine refer to the same `query` **variable**, and so all end up referencing its **last** known value.

To fix the issue, you need to change the definition:

```py
        @asyncio.coroutine
        def fake_json(self):
            return query
```

to a formulation that captures the value of `query`, such as:

```py
        @asyncio.coroutine
        def fake_json(self, query=query):
            return query
```

`await asyncio.sleep(5)` helps because it allows the `process_query` to run to completion before the value of `query` changes from under its feet. You'd get the same effect with `await process_query(R)`.

Two points unrelated to the question:

- The `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator is [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.coroutine) and there is no reason to use it in new code (unless you specifically aim for compatibility with pre-3.5 Python). Instead, simply define `fake_json` using `async def`.
- You don't need to call `__get__` to bind a `self` to `fake_json`, which isn't even using it. You can define a `fake_json` that doesn't `self` and simply assign `R.json = fake_json`.