# Is it possible that a button can pass himself in his own command?

Tags: python, tkinter

I created button dynamically and i want to give them a command to change their picture and change position. Now is the problem that i dont manage to pass the button himself in command

I exchanged the pictures in the code below with text but the problem is still the same.

It doesn't work with lambda or i haven't used it right.

```
from tkinter import *

karten = {'Stapel': [['D','A','BDA','D'],['D','2','BD2','D']]}
def p(button):
    button.config(text='HI')
RS = 'RS'
DA = 'DA'
D2 = 'D2'
root = Tk()
for i in karten:
    for j in karten[i]:
        vars()[j[2]] = Button(root,text=vars()[j[0]+j[1]],command=lambda: p(vars()[j[2]]))
        vars()[j[2]].pack()
root.mainloop()
```

i expected that the button changes the text but it only produced an error.

Comment: Should it be like `vars()[j[2]]` or was that just your attempt to make it work somehow?

Comment: that was my attempt

Comment: It's been a while, since I worked with Tkinter, but did you try subclassing Button to e.g. modify the way it handles the command, passing `self` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dict returned by `vars` is different inside the `lambda` and outside of it, thus you put your key in one dict, then try to retrieve it from another. Also, you should probably not use `vars` (or `globals` or `locals`) in the first place, if you can help it. (And for the `text`, using `vars()` does not make any sense whatsoever.)

Instead, you could just create a dedicated dictionary for the buttons in the global scope and access that one in your `lambda`. The values does not have to be present in the dict when you create the lambda, just when you call it.

```
buttons = {}
for i in karten:
    for j in karten[i]:
        b = Button(root, text=j[0]+j[1], command=lambda j=j: p(buttons[j[2]]))
        b.pack()
        buttons[j[2]] = b
```

Also note the `j=j` in the `lambda` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19837486/1639625) for more explanation).

Alternatively, you could use `configure` to set the `command` after creating the button and defining the variable, thus not needing the dictionary at all:

```
for i in karten:
    for j in karten[i]:
        b = Button(root, text=j[0]+j[1])
        b.configure(command=lambda b=b: p(b))
        b.pack()
```

Or using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) instead of `lambda b=b`:

```
        b.configure(command=functools.partial(p, b))
```