# lambdas in asyncio call_later

Tags: python, lambda, python-asyncio, partial

The Python 3.7.2 documentation on the asyncio eventloop says in the documentation of the `call_later` function:

> The optional positional args will be passed to the callback when it is called. If you want the callback to be called with keyword arguments use functools.partial().

Is using `functools.partial` considered superior to using `lambda` for this case?

Comment: `partial` will 'freeze' the arguments, which can help avoid a common mistake. See https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is using `functools.partial` considered superior to using `lambda` for this case?

"Superior" is too strong a word. It might be correct to say that `functools.partial` is the "one obvious choice" for simple argument binding.

Some possible advantages of `functools.partial` compared to `lambda` **not** implied by the above sentence:

- As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869491/lambdas-in-asyncio-call-later#comment96511679_54869491) by @AlexHall, `functools.partial` avoids the [late binding mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837486/python-lambda-in-a-loop) that often occurs when the lambda is created in a loop.
- `functools.partial` *might* make the intent clearer to some readers. (This is obviously individual, as readers with any FP background will typically have a strong preference for `lambda`.)
- In CPython `functools.partial` might be a tiny bit faster than `lambda` because it doesn't need to create a Python stack frame, nor does it need to perform the actual binding; its optimized C implementation just needs to execute the call on the object. The difference should be measured on a case-by-case basis.