# Why does calling a short chain of lambdas created by a for loop cause RecursionError while it works normally if created manually?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, lambda

I cannot see any relevant difference between the *for* version and the manual one, given the different outcomes:

```
# MANUAL version ==============================
lst = [lambda: 2]
lst.append(lambda: 2 * lst[0]())
lst.append(lambda: 2 * lst[1]())
lst.append(lambda: 2 * lst[2]())

print([item.__name__ for item in lst])
# ['<lambda>', '<lambda>', '<lambda>', '<lambda>']

print("result:", lst[-1]())
# result: 16

# FOR version ==============================
lst = [lambda: 2]
for i in range(3):
    print(i)
    lst.append(lambda: 2 * lst[i]())

print([item.__name__ for item in lst])
# ['<lambda>', '<lambda>', '<lambda>', '<lambda>']

print("result:", lst[-1]())
# 0
# 1
# 2
# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the `i` variable. You need bind the variable for each lambda. You can do so with the following syntax:
`lambda bound_i=i: 2 * lst[bound_i]()`

With this, I get the desired outcome. `result: 16`

I also found this question similar to yours : [Python Lambda in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837486/python-lambda-in-a-loop). It's a lot more in depth than my answer so it might be worth a read.

Comment: I am accepting this as a more direct solution, but @Luke Woodward one is better written. The link is also useful.

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```py
    lst.append(lambda: 2 * lst[i]())
```

the lambdas 'capture', or *close over*, the variables `lst` and `i`, not their values.

At the end of the loop, `i` has the value 2, and all elements in `lst` apart from the first are lambdas that return `2 * lst[2]()`, including `lst[2]`.  So, evaluating `lst[2]()` requires you to evaluate `lst[2]()`, which requires you to evaluate `lst[2]()`, and so on.

The fix is to create the lambdas inside a function:

```py
def makeLambda(i):
    return lambda: 2 * lst[i]()

lst = [lambda: 2]
for i in range(3):
    print(i)
    lst.append(makeLambda(i))
```

The reason this works is that each call into `makeLambda` creates a new scope, with new local variables for each lambda to close over.  The value of `i` within each separate function call doesn't change, and hence this produces the result you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation.