# Using lambda function in a loop

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to make a list of objects in python that each own 2 values: text, func
text is just a name assigned to it and func is a lambda function, all the code is a part of my project so I tried to represent that code section in a short code piece

```
l = []
for i in range(3):
    l.append(lambda: i)
for j in l:
    print(j())
```

now the output is

```
2
2
2
```

I understand that the output is all 2's because that's the last 'i' defined but I want the output to be:

```
0
1
2
```

without changing 'j' to 'i' (because I already know it will work and in my project I have no control over 'j')
in short, my question is: how do i make the lambda function to save the current 'i' instead of looking for the last 'i' defined

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837486/lambda-in-a-loop

Comment: put this in your loop instead, `l.append(lambda x=i: x)`

Comment: Use a factory function, `def func_maker(i): return lambda: i` then in your loop `l.append(func_maker(i))`