# How to define specific commands for each button included in each pane of a PanedWindow?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I want to create a PanedWindow with variable number of panes which every one of these panes includes a label and a button. Pressing a button in a pane should write a messege to the corresponding label in that pane.
I tried this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

n = 5
root = Tk()
root.geometry('250x500+100+100')

p = ttk.Panedwindow(root, orient=VERTICAL)
p.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, W, E))

for i in range(n):
    pane = ttk.Labelframe(p, width=25, borderwidth=0)
    p.add(pane)
    def writeToLabel():
        paneLabel.config(text='This is Pane number %d' %(i+1))
    paneLabel = ttk.Label(pane, width=20, relief='solid')
    paneButton = ttk.Button(pane, text='Press', command=writeToLabel)
    paneButton.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5)
    paneLabel.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=5)

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

But no matter which button is pressed the label in the last row is set with the message.

I would be grateful if somebody could help me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the sort of thing you are looking for:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

n = 5
root = Tk()
root.geometry('250x500+100+100')

p = ttk.Panedwindow(root, orient=VERTICAL)
p.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, W, E))


def writeToLabel(pl, i):
    pl.config(text='This is Pane number %d' %(i+1))

for i in range(n):
    pane = ttk.Labelframe(p, width=25, borderwidth=0)
    p.add(pane)
    paneLabel = ttk.Label(pane, width=20, relief='solid')
    paneButton = ttk.Button(pane, text='Press', command=lambda pl=paneLabel, i=i: writeToLabel(pl, i))
    paneButton.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5)
    paneLabel.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=5)

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Your current method does not work as the definition of `writeToLabel` will use the last value of `paneLabel` and `i`. You instead need to pass a reference to the label and the value of `i` using  a lambda function. The `pl=paneLabel` and `i=i` parts of the lambda function are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837486/lambda-in-a-loop).

Comment: It also has the same problem of getting the message just in the last pane.

Comment: I don't have that problem, are you sure you've copied it correctly?

Comment: Oops. I ran my own code again. Sorry. Yes you code helped me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70992879/how-to-define-specific-commands-for-each-each-pane-of-a-panedwindow