# Ending up with one queue when registering several queues with a manager

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Consider:

```py
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

def make_manager(q_names, port):
    qs = [Queue() for _ in q_names]
    class MyManager(SyncManager):
        pass
    for q_name, q in zip(q_names, qs):
        MyManager.register(q_name, callable=lambda: q)

    auth = b'myauth'
    try:
        manager = MyManager(address=('', port), authkey=auth)
        manager.start()
    except:
        print('Could not start manager')

    return manager

manager = make_manager(['aa', 'bb'], 8000)
print(manager.aa())
print(manager.bb())
```

The output is:

```
<multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x7f7ed1c83eb0>
<multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x7f7ed1c83eb0>
```

Why do both methods return the same queue?

**UPDATE**:
I figured out that the issue is about how `lambda` captures. Here is an example to illustrate:

```py
ll = []
for i in range(2):
    ll.append(lambda: i)
for l in ll:
    print(l()) # 1
```

I am still not sure how to get around this, but will search again as it's not related to `multiprocessing`.

**UPDATE**: Found it: [Lambda in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19837486/2725810)

Comment: What is your os?

Comment: @Charchit Ubuntu under WSL

Comment: I am voting to close my own question :)

Comment: Any reason why you are trying to do it like this anyway? You can use `manager.Queue` to create a managed queue for you instead. Also there is no reason to use `multiprocessing.Queue` inside a managed process, you can just use `queue.Queue` for that.

Comment: @Charchit Given that several clients can connect to the same queue, is `queue.Queue` safe?

Comment: If you use it with a manager, it is. This is because access to managed objects are handled through pipes internally anyway. In fact calling `manager.Queue` actually creates a `queue.Queue` rather than a `multiprocessing.Queue`. With that said, I am a little unsure whether it would be safe to do so with the method you are using (which, imo, is perhaps not the best) because you are sending over the entire queue instead of, for example, calling certain methods on the queue and passing their return values from the manager process to main. Best to test before committing.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding a workaround, instead of leaving it upto lamdba to do it for you, you can change your `qs` to this:

```
qs = [Queue for _ in q_names]
```

And change the `lambda` to this

```
lambda: q()
```

Since I do not have access to a UNIX device, I couldn't test this, so take it with a grain of salt

Comment: Won't you get a different queue each time you call `manager.aa()`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning was your goal to map a queue to a `typeid`, and extract it from different processes to get the same queue? If so then I think you might be reinventing the wheel here, you can use [Namespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.Namespace) for that. It was built for these kinds of things

Answer (score 0):

My own solution is as per the linked post:

```py
def make_manager(q_names, port):
    class MyManager(SyncManager):
        pass
    for q_name in q_names:
        q = Queue()
        MyManager.register(q_name, callable=lambda q=q: q)

    auth = b'myauth'
    try:
        manager = MyManager(address=('', port), authkey=auth)
        manager.start()
    except:
        print('Could not start manager')

    return manager
```